# How to get connected standby to play music with the screen off on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

When you play Spotify or Tidal or other music streaming services, the music stops if you have connected standby enabled in the registry and the screen turns off.

When connected standby is disabled and you choose "do nothing" when you close the screen, the music will continue to play, but then your machine stays in it's normal high-power state.

Is there any way on Windows 10 to put the machine into a low power state with the screen turned off but also be able to continue playing music like a smartphone does with the screen turned off?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. You should go to `Control Panel -> Power and Sleep Settings`. Then you should create a custom profile. Make Sure your PC will go to sleep over a extended period of time. If it's a laptop make sure it won't go to sleep if the screen lid is closed.

Comment: I want the computer to enter a low power state (sleep) but to still be able to play music. The Groove music app seems to be able to do this - it keeps on playing music when the screen is off and the computer enters Connected Standby. No other media players are able to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to playback during Modern Standby (S0 low power idle) must be supported not only by the hardware and OS, but [also by the App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby). From my experience, most Windows 10 music players in the Microsoft Store currently do not appear to support it. The only Store app that I have found that keeps playing (and streaming) music during Modern Standby is [foobar2000 mobile](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/foobar2000-mobile/9nblggh5xs5x). Give it a try.